# No classes available to schedule upon search. Why?

Tags: scheduled-job

The class I want to schedule is not appearing when I search for it in setting up a scheduled job. It has been used before, but I made a change to it so I deleted the existing scheduled job and tried to add it back. But when I click the magnifying glass to look for it, I get no results whatsoever. The security is set for Sys Admin, so it shouldn't have to do with that. Thoughts..?

Comment: Did you try typing in the name? I believe the default lookup only shows recently used classes...

Comment: oh wow. I had left it blank and searched by name when the box popped up...but when I entered the name first, lo and behold...

What a silly question, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I could help! ☺

Comment: @NatalieSpatharakis Why don't you go ahead and answer your own question here... :)

Comment: @JohnThompson I've never done that before, how funny! Will do.

Comment: @NatalieSpatharakis now go ahead and accept you own answer as the best one :)

Answer (score 1):

So...as it turns out, with that lookup field, the name you search should be written prior to hitting the magnifying glass as opposed to after. My bad!